# Publish app to Azure from VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to publish an app from Visual Studio Code to Azure App service directly i.e. without going through Git or some other source control?

Comment: The best technique would be the new [Zip Push Deploy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/10/16/zip-push-deployment-for-web-apps-functions-and-webjobs/), but someone would need to right a Code extension for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no native way of doing so. You can créate a Task in Visual Studio code that does the git push or ftp push or something. But no native way yet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, now it is possible: see [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/extensions).

But for now I would discourage you from using VS Code to deploy on Azure through the official extension, I'm facing plenty of errors and wasting tons of hours, even trying to publish a default basic MVC template: errors 404, 403, 500 (*"Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'"*)... it's a nightmare. It's even more unpleasant since they're all made by Microsoft, and they just don't work together.

Using the classical Visual Studio should work well.